# NSURLSession self as delegate in init or inner class?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I can't understand why I'm getting a `'self' used before super.init call` when creating the `NSURLSession` in the init.

This is the code I am using:

```
class MyClass: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate{

    private let urlSession: NSURLSession
    private let task : NSURLSessionTask
    private let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    private let url: NSURL

    init(url: NSString){

        self.url = NSURL(string: url)!
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
        task = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(self.url);
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Also I've seen code from other people where they create an inner class that implements the delegate and then have an instance of that class in the parent class and that instance is used as delegate. Is this the 'swifty' way of dealing with delegates?

Why my code isn't working? Should I use the inner class way? What are the advantages of doing that if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Swift, you are not permitted to refer to self until it has satisfied two phase initialization:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID220

You are referring to self when setting the delegate, but have not set all properties on your class or let NSObject set its properties.

**EDIT:** Found these solutions that you could try. I prefer the lazy var approach but that means you lose the constant which is a little frustrating...
http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/11/20/swift-initialisation.html